# How to get the difference between two times with SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server

I have the following two column with Time values

```
;WITH cte AS (
SELECT *
FROM (VALUES
('08:00:00','18:30:00'),
('20:00:00','08:00:00'),
('18:30:00','06:00:00'),
('08:00:00','18:30:00')) as t(time1, time2)
)
```

How can I get the following difference values:

```
result
 10.5
  12
 11.5
 10.5
```

I tried with DATEDIFF but I am never able to get a true values especially for the case from 18:30 to 6:00
I tried like this, but does not work for this case(8:30 to 6:00) ...

```
CASE
  WHEN GirisSaati > CikisSaati THEN cast( DATEDIFF(MINUTE, cast(CikisSaati as time ), cast(GirisSaati as time ))as float) / 60  
  WHEN GirisSaati <= CikisSaati THEN  cast( DATEDIFF(MINUTE,cast( GirisSaati as time ), cast(CikisSaati as time ) )as float) /60  
END
```

Hope to find help, thanks ...

Comment: Is there some kind of restriction that intervals are less than 24 hours? If not, how do you know whether 08:00-09:00 is 1 or 25 hours?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is how you can do it:

```
DECLARE @t table(time1 time, time2 time)
INSERT @t values
('08:00','18:30'), 
('20:00','08:00'),
('18:30','06:00'),
('08:00','18:30')   

;WITH CTE as
(
  SELECT 
    time1, time2,
    CASE WHEN time2 < time1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END 
      + CAST(time2 as datetime) - CAST(time1 as datetime) diff
FROM @t
)
SELECT 
  time1, 
  time2, 
  cast(diff as time) timediff, 
  cast(diff as float) * 24 decimaldiff
FROM CTE
```

Result:

```
time1  time2  timediff  decimaldiff
08:00  18:30  10:30     10.5
20:00  08:00  12:00     12
18:30  06:00  11:30     11.5
08:00  18:30  10:30     10.5
```

Comment: Btw, this method will also handle seconds and milliseconds when calculating the difference

Answer (score 6):

This is because you are dividing by 60, an integer.  This will return an integer result.  Instead try dividing by a numeric:

**Example**

```
DECLARE @Time1 TIME(0) = '08:00:00';
DECLARE @Time2 TIME(0) = '18:30:00';

SELECT      
    DATEDIFF(MINUTE, @Time1, @Time2) / 60       AS Incorrect,
    DATEDIFF(MINUTE, @Time1, @Time2) / 60.0     AS Correct

;
```

**Result**

```
Incorrect   Correct
10          10.500000
```

This is a consequence of [data type precedence](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190309.aspx).  From MSDN:

> When an operator combines two expressions of different data types, the
>   rules for data type precedence specify that the data type with the
>   lower precedence is converted to the data type with the higher
>   precedence. If the conversion is not a supported implicit conversion,
>   an error is returned. When both operand expressions have the same data
>   type, the result of the operation has that data type.

In this case INT has the highest precedence.

Alternatively you could use [CAST](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms187928.aspx) to explicitly set the [data type](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms187752.aspx): `CAST(60 AS DECIMAL(18,2))`.

Comment: the problem you have solved was already handled differently in the code of the question. The issue described in the question is that sometimes the second timestamp is after midnight and lower than the first timestamp

Answer (score 0):

I found another option...

**Step 1** -> Create this SQL function

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[get_TimeDefferance_hh_mm_ss]
(
    -- Add the parameters for the function here
    @FromTime time,@ToTime time
)
RETURNS time
AS
BEGIN
    declare @totalsec decimal(10,2)= datediff(SECOND,@FromTime,@ToTime);
    declare @secondPart int= @totalsec%60
    --select @secondPart As secondpart
    declare @totalminsOnly int= (@totalsec-@secondPart)/60

declare @MinsPart int=@totalminsOnly%60
--select @MinsPart AS minsPart

declare @totalHoursOnly int= (@totalminsOnly-@MinsPart)/60

--select @totalHoursOnly AS totalhoursonly

-- Return the result of the function
RETURN cast(@totalHoursOnly AS varchar(50))+':'+cast(@MinsPart as varchar(50))+':'+cast(@secondPart as varchar(50))
```

END

**Step 2**->Go to new query and check is it working..

```
declare @FromTime time='2:30:41';
declare @ToTime time='4:20:30';

declare @timeDiff time= **dbo.get_TimeDefferance_hh_mm_ss(@FromTime,@ToTime)**  
select @timeDiff
```

**output**---
01:49:49.0000000

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it is a 'bit' later, but I will post my solution in order to help someone else.

```
set @from = '10:15';
set @to = '12:30';

select (time_to_sec(timediff(@to, @from))/3600);
```

Output is 2.2500