# Subtracting Time Intervals in SQL

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have a table with 2 rows of time intervals. The data is stored as a varchar containing the hour and minutes, like the sample data below. I need to find a way to subtract the first column of data from the second and keep it as a time interval format. As seen below in the following table, I want to subtract colB from colA, to get the numbers in desiredOutcome displayed in the same format.

| colA | colB | desiredOutcome |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 10:30 | 1:30 | 9:00 |
| 1:50 | 1:47 | 0:03 |
| 20:10 | 15:15 | 4:55 |
| 250:10 | 50:05 | 200:05 |

Any and all help is greatly appreciated

EDIT:
To clarify, these are time intervals, not times of the day. I have added more data to the table to show this, it is the amount of time taken in hours and minutes to perform a task. Also, the data is stored in varchar, but I can just use CAST() to change that.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get the difference between two times with SQL Server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35916492/how-to-get-the-difference-between-two-times-with-sql-server)

Comment: Problem #1: storing time as `varchar`. Also looks like you want to subtract `colB` from `colA` rather than the other way round. Do you have any values that are over 24 hours?

Comment: Yes, I want to do colA-colB = desiredOutcome. Also yes, there are values over 24 hours in the data. Also, the link provided does not answer my question, it is getting the difference between times of day instead of between measurements of time.

Answer (score 0):

Will say would have recommended storing this as simple minutes using a data type like int, then format for the user to your HH:MM format. It would make calculations like this a lot easier.

So for example instead of storing `250:10`, would have stored it as `15010` minutes

Below I converted your HH:MM time lengths to minutes, did the calculation, and then formatted it back again.

### Calculating Difference Between HH:MM Time Lengths

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #Interval
CREATE TABLE #Interval (ID INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY, colA Varchar(10),colB Varchar(10))

INSERT INTO #Interval
VALUES
('10:30','1:30')
,('1:50','1:47')
,('20:10','15:15')
,('250:10','50:05')

SELECT *
    ,DesiredOutcome = CONCAT(FLOOR(DeltaInMinutes/60.0),':',FORMAT(DeltaInMinutes % 60,'0#'))
FROM #Interval AS A
/*Find the colons*/
CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT idxA = NULLIF(CHARINDEX(':',A.ColA),0)
        ,idxB = NULLIF(CHARINDEX(':',A.ColB),0)
) AS B
/*Break up into hours and minutes*/
CROSS APPLY(
    SELECT HrsA =   ISNULL(SUBSTRING(A.ColA,0,idxA),0)
        ,HrsB =     ISNULL(SUBSTRING(A.ColB,0,idxB),0)
        ,MinutesA = ISNULL(SUBSTRING(A.ColA,idxA+1,100),0)
        ,MinutesB = ISNULL(SUBSTRING(A.ColB,idxB+1,100),0)
) AS C
/*Find total duration in minutes*/
CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT TotalMinutesA = (HrsA * 60) + MinutesA
    ,TotalMinutesB = (HrsB * 60) + MinutesB
) AS D
/*Calculate delta*/
CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT DeltaInMinutes = TotalMinutesA - TotalMinutesB
) AS E
```